# Using try/catch to display errors depending on input

Tags: c#, arrays, try-catch

I have a rather basic assignment that involves using `try/catch` to show a number of names depending on the number entered(using an array). If the number entered is too large it may still display the names but also has to give an out of bounds error. If a word or something similar is used it needs to give a format error.

So far my code works reasonably well since it can display an out of bounds error but when I enter a word I do not get a format error.

I would also like to know if there would be a possibility to cause an error to occur if the number is lower than 5(in a situation where only 5 is accepted).

here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = new string[5] { "Merry", "John", "Tim", "Matt", "Jeff" };
            string read = Console.ReadLine();
            int appel;

        try
        {   
            int.TryParse(read, out appel);
            for (int a = 0; a < appel; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(names[a]);
            }


        }



        catch(FormatException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a format error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, is outside the range of 5. Error message: {1}", e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("out of range error. error message: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `int.TryParse` doesn't throw exceptions, intead it returns `true` if conversion succeed, and `false` otherwise

Comment: You shouldn't catch all those exceptions but test your parameters before instead.

Comment: why do you want to throw and exception where a number is lower than 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int.TryParse(read, out appel);
```

This code will not throw any exception, this will either return True(if parsing succeeds else false).
If you intend to throw an exception use: [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That was the perfect answer, now it all makes sense again :D

Answer (score 0):

```
        bool b = int.TryParse(read, out appel);
        if(!b)
           throw new FormatException("{0} is not a valid argument", read);
```

or

```
        int.Parse(read, out appel);
```

which will throw a formatexception whenever the wrong value is entered.